# Proving differential of map to be non-zero.

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from notes from which I am studying and I was unable to prove the following result:

> Let M be a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let $P \in M$ and let $(U, \phi) $ be a slice chart around P, then define $M\cap U=${$x\in U : \phi_{n+1} (x) =0$} . Then prove that $(d\phi_{n+1} )_p \neq 0$ .

Definitions :Here $(U , \phi) $ be slice chart which means that $\phi( M \cap U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ .

If $M^n \subseteq N^{n+1}$ is a submanifold, we say that M is a hypersurface of N.

I am not sure how exactly should I proceed in proving that ?  I am not very good at it and that's why  I am reading notes for the 2nd time. This question is from section hyperplanes.
This result has to be used in proving: Let M be a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ , then locally M is the graph of a smooth function.

I hope that much information is sufficient to answer this question.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a ($C^1$) slice chart $\phi: (U,U\cap M, p)\to (\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R}^n\times 0,(\odot,0))$, ($\odot$ is the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$) taking the derivative we get $T_p\phi:(T_p U, T_pM)\to (T_{(\odot,0)}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, T_{\odot}\mathbb{R}^n)$. Since $\phi$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, $T_p\phi$ is a linear isomorphism. Since $T_{(\odot,0)}\mathbb{R}^{n+1} = T_\odot \mathbb{R}^n\oplus T_0\mathbb{R}$, if $\beta=(b_1,...,b_n,b_{n+1})$ is a basis adapted to this splitting (e.g. the standard basis), then $T_p\phi^{-1}(\beta)=(T_p\phi^{-1}(b_1),...,T_p\phi^{-1}(b_n),T_p\phi^{-1}(b_{n+1}))$ is a basis of $T_pU$ adapted to the splitting $T_pU=T_pM\oplus \langle T_p\phi^{-1}(b_{n+1})\rangle$. With respect to these bases the matrix representing $T_p\phi$ is the identity matrix; its bottom row corresponds to $(d\phi_{n+1})_p$, so that in particular $(d\phi_{n+1})_p\neq0$.